# Getting Process ID Linux using pgrep

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep

I have a bash script called `run.sh` which launches two python scripts `meter_1.py` and `meter_2.py`

```
#!/bin/sh

./meter_1.py &
./meter_2.py &
```

When the scripts are running and I search for the PID of the scripts using the command

```
ps -aux | grep python
```

The output is

```
openhab+  9328 84.0  1.6  25320 16580 pts/0    R    22:23   0:04 python ./meter_1.py
openhab+  9329 84.6  1.6  25320 16596 pts/0    R    22:23   0:04 python ./meter_2.py
```

Using the pgrep command I can get the the PID

```
>pgrep python 
9328 
9329
```

However I could have multiple python scripts running and I want to get the process ID name by the script it is running not based on if it is python or not.

For example:

```
>pgrep python" "./meter_1.py
9328
```

Is there a functionality for this in `pgrep`? The following seems to work however it would be nice to get just the process ID back.

```
>ps -aux | grep python" "./meter_1.py
openhab+  9328 84.0  1.6  25320 16580 pts/0    R    22:23   0:04 python ./meter_1.py
```

Comment: Add the `-l` option or combine with `-a`

Comment: Unfortunately ```-l``` just gave out  ```<PID> python```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ba(sh) you can get the PID of the last started process with `$!`

so in your `run.sh` script you can simply use:

```
#!/bin/sh

./meter_1.py &
echo PID of process1: $!
./meter_2.py &
echo PID of process2: $!
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but I do not need the PID right away it could be X minutes/hours later after I've launched many other processes. I could use this to write it to a file but then I'd have to maintain a separate file of PID's, surely must be some way to just grab the PID as you need it.

Comment: Usually when apps are developed, the PID is written in a `lock file` for each process, which gets maintained, so you have an easy way of finding the needed PIDs when you need them, right away or later...

Comment: Thanks Ron, I am going to use a variation of your solution to write to a file for now, I will mark yours as the solution tomorrow if no one has a way to get it immediately just want to see if any more answers come in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the process, like you're the one starting the process in a script, to expand on what have posted already.

```
#!/bin/sh
./meter_1.py & meter_1_py_pid=$!
./meter_2.py & meter_2_py_pid=$!
```

The pids are in the variables `$meter__1_py_pid` and `$meter__2_py_pid`
You can do whatever you want with the pids, check if it is running, kill it and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! To explain a little more I will be using them to kill the process and restart them again when another JSON file is updated or if the file does not need to be updated just to ensure they are still running and not to launch 2 instances of the process.

Comment: Ok, so you might need a lock for your process to make sure there is only one running at a time. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement for some info and tips, I found a lot of useful stuffs in there that I still use and will use.

Comment: This link was very useful thanks for that, I ended up launching the process's from another python script and storing the PID's in a JSON file so I can check if they are still running. I am a bit under pressure as it is for a final year project but I am definitely going to look into lock files for future projects!